# Set of Cauchy sequences is closed in the metric space of bounded functions.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

I already proved this result by showing that the set of sequences that are not Cauchy is open, but I was wondering whether it can be demonstrated more directly in the following way:

Let $f:\mathbb{N}\mapsto M$ be an adherent point of the set of Cauchy sequences, then there is a sequence $(f_j)$, where each $f_j: \mathbb{N}\mapsto M$ represents a Cauchy sequence, such that $(f_j)$ converges to $f$. We show that $f$ is also Cauchy. For a sufficiently large $j$, the functions $f_j$ share a number $N$ such that $m,n > N$ implies that $d(f_j(m), f_j(n)) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Then, choosing this $N$, we have
\begin{align*}
    d(f(m),f(n)) &= d\left(\lim_{j \rightarrow \infty} f_j(m), \lim_{j \rightarrow \infty} f_j(n)\right)
    \\&= \lim_{j \rightarrow \infty} d(f_j(m), f_j(n)) \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}<\varepsilon
\end{align*}

Does it make any sense?

Comment: What is a "Cauchy function"? ("...$f$ is also Cauchy")

Comment: It represents a Cauchy sequence. Since we're in the space of bounded functions I thought it makes more sense to work with functions, but it's not really necessary. Just notation, really.

Comment: When you say $(f_n)$ converges to $f$, do you mean pointwise or uniformly?

Comment: @aduh Uniformly, because $(f_n) \rightarrow f$ in the sup metric.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Using the uniform convergence, let $N$ be such that $d(f_N(m),f(m)) < \epsilon/3$ for all $m \in \mathbb N$.

Using the fact that $f_N$ is Cauchy, let $M$ be such that $d(f_N(m) ,f_N(n)) < \epsilon/3$ for all $m,n \geq M$.

Then, if $m,n \geq M$,
$$d(f(m), f(n)) \leq d(f(m),f_N(m)) + d(f_N(m),f_N(n)) + d(f_N(n), f(n)) < \epsilon.$$

So, $f$ is Cauchy.